# Problema al cargar una imagen en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, imagen

Tengo este formulario donde se recibe un archivo de una imagen por medio del usuario

```
<label for="logo">Logo de la Página Web:</label>
<input type="file" id="logo" name="logo" accept="image/*" required>
```

y se recoje en el controlador donde luego se retorna a la vista, tambien se sube la ruta del archivo a la base de datos

```
if ($request->hasFile('logo')) {
            $logoPath = $request->file('logo')->store('logos', 'public');
            $web->logo_path = $logoPath;
        }

$logo = $request->file('logo');
return view('pagina_web',
            compact('colorPrincipal', 'colorSecundario', 'logo', 'productos_formateados'));
```

Entonces ahora en la vista me gustaria mostrar la imagen, tengo esto pero no se porque no me funciona

```
<img class="logo" src="{{ asset('storage/'.$logo->store('logos', 'public')) }}" alt="Logo">
```

He creado la carpeta storage/logos pero aun no consigo mostrar el logo, y me sale siempre algo como lo que he adjuntado en la imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: la ruta parece estar mal, puedes abrir las heramientas de desarrollador del navegador web y verificar si hay algun error de permiso (acceso a la ruta) o si la ruta es incorrecta en la propiedad src

Comment: en teoria el metodo asset deberia estar retornando una ruta/path... si debuggeas que retorna puedes ver si hay algo que no este funcionando bien ..

Comment: Voy a revisarlo y te comento

Comment: ok, me dices a ver si hay algun cambio...

Comment: Si el problema es que esta ruta no esta correctamente indicada @if($logo)
            <img class="logo" src="{{ asset('storage/'.$logo->store('logos', 'public')) }}" alt="Logo">
        @endif

Comment: lo resolviste???

Comment: Si he subido la respuesta con el problema resuelto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despues de varios dias he consegido hacerlo
Primero intente guardar los logos que introducia el usuario desde el controlador:
`$logo = $request->file('logo')->store('logos', 'public');`
Esto hace que el logo se guarde forma local en la carpeta storage/logos.
Y para que la ruta nos funcione y sea publica a todo el mundo necesitamos hacer lo siguiente en la terminal:
`php artisan storage:link`
Ahora cargamos la foto en la vista `<img src="{{ asset('storage/' . $logo) }}" alt="Logo de la Página Web">`